# The standard 16 colors supported with the Windows VGA palette... but transparent

Tags: colors, transparent, hex

I have the following list of colors:

```
'#00FFFF','#00FF00','#FFFF00','#FFFFFF','#C0C0C0','#808000','#808080','#008080','#008000','#FF00FF','#800000','#FF0000','#000080','#800080','#000000','#0000FF'
```

These are the hexidecimal codes for the standard 16 colors (as found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors)). I'm looking for the transparent version of all of these codes. Can I just add something to these codes to make them transparent? Or is there a list of the transparent codes too?

Comment: There are no transparent RGB values, how a gif/png etc handles transparency is specific to the format. RGBA has an alpha channel for transparency... the answer to your question will depend on what it is you want to *do* with these colours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't find transparent codes for your colours (each HEX is a color)

The only thing you can do is to use #transparent.

Hexadecimal transparency : [Check here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070507072903AAsDNnE)

You can try your colour here : [Colour Tester](http://www.colorcombos.com/combotester.html)